# iphone screenshot specific area

Tags: iphone, screenshot

I have a View including a Toolbar and a WebView

```
UIVIEW
  UIToolbar
  UIWebview
```

Now i like to make a screenshot ONLY from the WebView with:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(articleWebView.window.bounds.size);     
    [articleWebView.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *screenImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But always ImageCapture starts from the TOP of the Screen.
So it includes the Toolbar (even 20 empty pixel at the top from the Statusbar)

How can I just capture the Image thats actual in my UIWebView?

Thanks Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UIWebView is backed by its own layer, so you should be able to just grab the currently displayed contents for it:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(articleWebView.bounds.size);     
[articleWebView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```