# iPhone: can i save the screen or take screen shot to practicular area of view

Tags: iphone

On my screen there is an image and I have to save this image by taking a screenshot. Is there any other way of saving a particular area of the image only?

If there is a method, please guide me with a simple example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone screenshot specific area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333693/iphone-screenshot-specific-area)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will allow you to grab just a section of the screen, you could adapt for full screen

```
    CGRect screenRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);

[self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    //if you want to save this image to the photo album uncomment the next line
//UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

If you simply want to get a screenshot though just press the home and top button together which will put a screenshot in the photo album each time you do it

Answer (score 1):

If you need a programming way to achieve this you could use:

```
[[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[view dataWithPDFInsideRect:[view bounds]]];
```

Comment: thank you i will try this and get back to you, if i have any problem

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing the home and close/power button at the same time.

Comment: hi weltraumpirat, ru kidding me, i dont know wether that method exits r not, so i asked you guys

Comment: No, I wasn't kidding.  All I did was answer your question.  If you simply want to take a screen shot, that's how you do it.  Maybe you should try being more specific:  What are you trying to do?

Comment: hi weltraumpirat, my problem is i working in augmentation reality app,i use two view one is camera and other is transprant view for drawing on camera view, to save image, i place UIButton of view, after pressing UIButton screen shot take, with UIButton image is saving, i want to save image without UIButton, tell me how to solve this problem. tell all way, thank you